# Unwanted None printed when asking for input

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code seems to be printing a `None` at the end of the code. I read that it is due to several print statements, but I'm not sure how to fix it in my case:

```
def type(str):
    for char in str:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.075)
    time.sleep(1.5)

input1 = input(type("""\na. You go to the printer
b. Go to keyboard"""))
```

output:

```
a. You go to the printer
b. Go to keyboardNone
```

How can I get rid of the extra `None` in the end?

Answer (score 1):

`type` here returns `None`, which is fed to `input`, which will then write it after `type` has finished execution, so, first, I would recommend changing the name of the function `type` to something else, because `type` is a built-in Python function, and by defining your own, you're shadowing the original, second, you could call `type` before asking for input:

```
type("""\na. You go to the printer
b. Go to keyboard""")

input1 = input()
```

The note about `type` can also be said of the parameter name `str` of `type`, `str` is also a built-in Python function, and using it as a parameter name will shadow the built-in function but only in the scope of the function in which it is defined (`type`), so I would recommend changing that too.